# Custom adapter returning null for fragment views

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I am currently trying to create an app which consists of a gridview as the main layout and fill the gridview with Fragments which may be expanded to replace the main view when clicked.  My issue is that my custom adapter is returning null for my fragments views and causing force closes upon starting the app... or so I believe.  The fragments also all have their layouts declared programatically... I added blank ids and set them using setId(R.id.blahblah)... wondering if maybe that has something to do with the issue

```
11-06 17:18:58.119  28254-28254/com.osiris.basket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2451)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Custom Adapter:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public FragmentAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

private Fragment[] mEggs = {
        //new DessertCase(mContext),
        //new Nyandroid(mContext),
        new Logo(mContext)
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mEggs.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mEggs[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    Fragment frag = mEggs[i];
    return frag.getId();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Fragment frag = mEggs[position];
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        view = frag.getView();
        //view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        //view.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

One of the fragments:

```
public class Logo extends Fragment {
Toast mToast;
ImageView mContent;
int mCount;
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
public String n;
private Context context;

public Logo(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

private View makeView() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(context);
    view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    view.setId(R.id.beanbag);

    view.setLayoutParams(
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ));
    final int p = (int) (8 * metrics.density);
    view.setPadding(p, p, p, p);

    Typeface light = Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL);
    Typeface normal = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.BOLD);

    final float size = 14 * metrics.density;
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    lp.bottomMargin = (int) (-4 * metrics.density);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    if (light != null) tv.setTypeface(light);
    tv.setTextSize(1.25f * size);
    tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    tv.setShadowLayer(4 * metrics.density, 0, 2 * metrics.density, 0x66000000);
    tv.setText("Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    view.addView(tv, lp);

    tv = new TextView(context);
    if (normal != null) tv.setTypeface(normal);
    tv.setTextSize(size);
    tv.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    tv.setShadowLayer(4 * metrics.density, 0, 2 * metrics.density, 0x66000000);

    if (SDK_INT == 9 || SDK_INT == 10) {
        n = "Gingerbread";
    } else if (SDK_INT == 11 || SDK_INT == 12 || SDK_INT == 13) {
        n = "Honeycomb";
    } else if (SDK_INT == 14 || SDK_INT == 15) {
        n = "ICS";
    } else if (SDK_INT >= 15) {
        n = "JELLY BEAN";
    }

    tv.setText(n);
    view.addView(tv, lp);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    mToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mToast.setView(makeView());

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    mContent = new ImageView(context);
    mContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.platlogo_alt);
    mContent.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    final int p = (int) (32 * metrics.density);
    mContent.setPadding(p, p, p, p);

    mContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mToast.show();
            mContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.platlogo);
        }
    });

    mContent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
                        .addCategory("com.osiris.beanbag.BeanBag"));
                //.setClassName("com.android.systemui","com.android.systemui.beanbag"));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                android.util.Log.e("PlatLogoActivity", "Couldn't find a bag of beans.");
            }
            getActivity().finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
    //mContent.setId(R.id.beanbag);
}
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.id.beanbag, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getView method on fragment "frag.getView()". It returns Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided. : found on developer.android.com. In onCreateView you are inflating "R.id.beanbag". If you look at some samples you can see that here you are suppose to inflate layout like "R.layout.xml_file_in_res_layout"